# Writing to Garmin IMG format from FME or other tools

Tags: garmin, workflow, gme

At my workplace we manage protected areas. The maps on their GPSes do not update often enough. Typically enough they are the ones setting up signs for the general public.

Our rangers would like to have access to the newest protected areas on their GPS. They are predominantly using Garmin. The protected areas are represented by relativle simple polygons. Styling could be very simplified; one color per category (national park/landscape protected area/etc) and a border line.

I want to establis a workflow where protected areas are exported and made available in the garmin img-format or similar. I will probably do this using FME Server, but it seems FME can not write [garmin img-files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garmin_.img)

Are there open source libraries available which can write garmin img-files which can be integrated with the FME workflow??

Comment: This is probably the best starting point https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Map_On_Garmin also for non-OSM data. Unfortunately some new Garmin devices do not support home made maps in .img format.

Comment: Another thought is to render the vector data into raster, and find a way of converting to a raster .kmz for the Garmin devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wiki article from OpenStreetMap project is probably the best starting point https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Map_On_Garmin also for non-OSM data. Unfortunately some new Garmin devices do not support home made maps in .img format. It is quite tedious to create the first working Garmin .img with these tools. Let's hope that OSM has a good coverage on your area because then you may find a site that delivers pre-compiled .img files.

Comment: Sounds promising that there are some relevant tools. But we will have to provide the data since we are the actual owners producers of this data set. So for now workflow looks like this DB -> OSM-format - > magic command line library -> Garmin IMG.